# Apt upgrade failure due to "python3-samba": Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, samba

Something is going wrong with the package "python3-samba".
As a result, I cannot proceed with any upgrade due to this package.
I have tried removing the aforementioned package but in vain.
I have also removed all the associated with the troublesome package files from /var/lib/dpkg/info.
I tried also to reconfigure the dpkg database with no luck:

```
root@lubuntuhome:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package python3-samba (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-samba
```

The release of Ubuntu I am using is: `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS`
The version of the package I am using is:

```
python3-samba:
  Installed: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
 *** 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:4.15.5~dfsg-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

The current status is depicted in the following picture:
[image]

Shall I proceed with force overwriting of the file causing this error?

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-samba_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Please advise!

Comment: More info for the question needs to be added to the question with edit. Do not use comments for more info. Is there a chance you have tried to update or upgrade or change any part of python?

Comment: You are right. I've just updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following command and my issue has been resolved!

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-samba -f
```